# How does one close stdin from the windows CMD prompt?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, stdin

I know that one can close `stdin` when executing a command from a Linux CLI using logic such as:

```
0<&- <command>
```

This simulates/emulates running an application unattended, or within a CI/CD system such as Jenkins/Gitlab that has stdin closed.

Why do I care? Because we have an application that has a "Press any key to continue..." prompt.

When run under Jenkins/Gitlab or anything that doesn't have stdin open, it just moves on..... when run on Linux.

How would I do this, and is this possible to do this from the Windows CMD Window CLI?

I've tried `0<&-` and that results in the message

```
0<& was unexpected at this time.
```

Google search gives many hits for stdin but all the documentation is on redirection. I haven't found anything for windows for closing.

Comment: `command <nul` might work (or not - depends on how `command` is programmed)

Comment: Wow! Yeah! That did it! Change your comment to an answer @Stephan so I can accept it. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
command <nul
```

which basically means "take any input from the NUL device (as an infinite source of "CRLF"'s). This works as long as `command` takes its input from STDIN (like the `pause` command) *and* doesn't flush the input buffer (like the `choice` command)

If you need textual input (like the `set /p` command), you need another approach:

```
echo inputtext|command
```